# What was the time control in tata steel tournament?

Tags: tournament, time-control

Does anyone know, what the exact time control was for the groups A and B in the
 tata steel tournament last month ?

I remember something with 100 minutes for 40 moves and 50 minutes for 20 moves
 and 15 minutes for the rest and 30 seconds increment from move 1. Is this
 correct ? And was the time control identical for group A and group B ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.tatasteelchess.com/tournament/information

Time control

The time control is: 100 minutes for 40 moves, followed by 50 minutes for 20 moves, then 15 minutes for the remaining moves with 30 seconds cumulative increment for each move starting from the first move.

So you remembered correctly.

And, yes, should be the same for A and B.